# How to use numbers in sed command?

Tags: linux, regex, sed

I have a file that contains this pattern:

```
X   10
X   523
X   78
```

now I want to use `sed` command to subtract the numbers in each line by 2 as below:

```
X   8
X   521
X   76
```

If this pattern is `X   100` to `X   200` and I want to use `for` command how can I use a combination of `for` and `sed`?

I tried this but did not work:

`for i in {100..200}; do sed -i 's/X   $i/X   $(i-2)/g' file.txt; done`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @grawity I want to use it with `for` command. I'll edit the question. For example it is 100 to 200.

Comment: @grawity I added my try to the question sorry for editing many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers are guaranteed to be greater than 0, you can use:

```
sed -i '
    s/\b[0-9]\+\b/&♪/; t a
    :a
    s/9♪/♪8/; t b
    s/8♪/♪7/; t b
    s/7♪/♪6/; t b
    s/6♪/♪5/; t b
    s/5♪/♪4/; t b
    s/4♪/♪3/; t b
    s/3♪/♪2/; t b
    s/2♪/♪1/; t b
    s/1♪/♪0/; t b
    s/0♪/♪9/; t a
    :b
    s/♪//
    s/\b0*\([0-9]\)/\1/
' file.txt
```

(This decrements by one. To decrement by two, run it twice. It doesn't support negative numbers... yet.)

If you don't mind losing nice column alignment, you can also use 'awk':

```
awk '{$2 -= 2; print}' file.txt > file_new.txt
```

---

Your 'for' example did not work because you're using incorrect quotes and incorrect expansions – variable expansion only happens inside double quotes, single quotes, and the math expression operator is `$(( ))`, not `$( )`.

```
for i in {100..200}; do sed -i "s/X   $i/X   $((i-2))/g" file.txt; done
```

Comment: The last command worked properly I use `' '` instead of `" "` but did not work. Thanks.